# Excel Solver, force variable to be non-zero

Tags: excel, solver

I need to use the solver from Excel to minimize an error.

The problem is that one of the variables to be changed is used in a denominator, so making it 0 causes `#DIV/0` error.

The optimizer has an option "Make unconstrained Variables Non-Negative", however I need this variables to also be Non-Zero.

I am using the GRG Non Linear and tick the option "Make unconstrained Variables Non-Negative"

Is there a way to tell the solver to never try 0 values so it doesn't run in a DIV/0 error, or tell it to not break when finding DIV/0 values and continue iterating.

Comment: havent seen an option. Another thing it would work for me is making a helper column where I substitute a DIV/0 value by a large number, so the sum of errors will keep being a number and a very large one, so it wont be considered a solution and wont make the solver crash

Answer (score 1):

Set a constraint for that variable that it is greater or equal to 1. Or just greater than 1, depends what you need to achieve.

```
$A$1>=1
```

Or:

```
$A$1>$B$1
```

Where cell B1 has 1 or 2 or 33 in it.

Edit:
Adding constraints in the Solver is simple:
[image]

Comment: I don't see any place to put constrains. I have used a workaround and is to use a helper column where I convert DIV/0 values to large values and then I compute the error from this helper column

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki adding constraints using the Add, Change buttons. Shown one as an example.